# When to move house to get into Junior School?

Tags: primary-schooler, school, united-kingdom

My daughter is in Year 2. I am going to move from North London to Bromley.

As far as I understand, good schools are full and cannot increase class size.
I've noticed that some junior schools have more places in Year 3 than linked infant schools have in Year 2. For example, Highfield Infant has 90 places in Year 2 but Highfield Junior has 96 places in Year 3.

When is it the best time to move in the area and apply for Year 3 places (e.g. January, July, September)?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I hope someone will be able to offer an answer for you, however questions like this, MAY be to localized for Parenting SE.  Good Luck!

Comment: It may help to talk with teachers, administrators, or other leaders, and parents at each of the schools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm aware this will be too late for the OP, but you never know who it may help...)

The answer needed is that applications should be made by early February and ideally move house in July to make a clean start in Year 3 in September.

The full procedure for [making a primary school place application](http://www.bromley.gov.uk/info/13/primary_school_admissions/72/making_a_primary_school_place_application/2) is detailed on the Bromley Council Website.

Comment: Yes it is too late (already moved) but thank you anyway!